# Bóton de atrás en el título de la activity con envio de parametros

Tags: android, android-studio

Quiero mostrar la típica flecha de atrás en una actividad y que al hacer click sobre ella me lleve a la actividad anterior pero adicionalmente pueda enviar parametros, use el siguiente codigo pero solo me envia a la activity anterior sin los parametros que estoy necesitando...

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Mi pregunta es como hacer para hacer la flecha atrs en la activity pero que se puedan enviar parametros?

Agradesco su ayuda.

Comment: En realidad debes sobreescribir onBackPressed() pero debes realizar lo que describo en mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar una acción cuando el `NavigateUp` es seleccionado, puedes hacerlo de 2 formas, con `onSupportNavigateUp` o con `onOptionsItemSelected`, entonces lo que te quedaría hacer es guardar los datos al momento en que se ejecute esta acción según el método que decidas usar, puedes usar `SharedPreferences` con `Gson` según lo que quieras almacenar, o `SQlite`, es cuestión de que necesites hacer, o con cual de estas formas de persistencia de datos estés mas familiarizado, entonces, teniendo en cuenta eso, se haría de esta forma:

**onSupportNavigateUp:**

```
@Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
        // Accion de almacenar data
    }
```

**onOptionsItemSelected:**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // Accion de almacenar data 
                break;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Al momento de obtener el `R.id.home`, estamos obteniendo el identificador de ese botón para poder asignarle una acción según nuestra necesidad.

Cualquiera de los 2 métodos te funciona para lo que necesitas hacer, pero debes tener una cosa en cuenta para la implementación. si sobrescribes el método `onOptionsItemSelected`, entonces el `onSupportNavigateUp` no sera llamado. Espero te funcione.

Answer (score 1):

> Mi pregunta es como hacer para hacer la flecha atrs en la activity
>   pero que se puedan enviar parámetros?

Para enviar datos de retorno desde la "Activity destino" que abres, hacia la "Activity origen" debes realizar lo siguiente:

Primeramente es importante usar `startActivityForResult()` desde tu "Activity origen" para que puedas obtener datos cuando regreses a la Activity y estos serán obtenido en el método `onActivityResult()` así que debes sobreescribirlo:

```
    private final static int REQUEST_CODE = 255;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                    //*Importante usar startActivityForResult() para que los datos sean obtenidos en onActivityResult()
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

            }
        });

   }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent dataIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, dataIntent);

        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    //* Aquí recibes el parametro enviado.
                    String messageReturn = dataIntent.getStringExtra("message_return");

                }
        }
    }
```

Ahora en la `Activity` que va a ser cerrada sobrescribe el método `onBackPressed()` y define la información que vas a enviar a la Activity que originalmente abrio  tu Activity :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("message", "Hola Argentina, Hola Yeimer!.");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();

}
```

Lo que sucederá aquí es que cuando cierres la Activity, esta enviara información a la Activity origen y esta información será recibida en el método `onActivityResult()`.